# JQ Widgets Chart with AngularJS Display Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, jqwidget

I`m trying to use a *chart using JQ widget* ,below snippet contains my controller code,
When I`m  making an ajax call to fetch data from server then 
i`m able to get the response but the chart takes previous data of that variable
i.e. undefined .
If i`m hard coding the same data in controller then its working .
I guess on-load its taking the value,how should i send ajax response data to chart.

I`m new to these things ,Please let me know what should i do in this case to send the data to chart.

This my tag in UI :-

```html
JQDemo.controller("charts", function ($scope, $timeout,$http) {
    // prepare chart data as an array
//    var sampleData = [
//            { State: 'Maharastra', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 25 },
//            { State: 'Karnataka', AccountsOpened: 25, VerificationPending: 25, Rejected: 0},
//            { State: 'Tamil Nadu', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 25 },
//            { State: 'AP', AccountsOpened: 20, VerificationPending: 20, Rejected: 25},
//            { State: 'Bihar', AccountsOpened: 0, VerificationPending: 20, Rejected: 25 },
//            { State: 'Odisha', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 30},
//            { State: 'UP', AccountsOpened: 20, VerificationPending: 40, Rejected: 0 }
//        ];
 
 var sampleData=[{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"AP","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"Calcutta","VerificationPending":"2","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"Delhi","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"5"},{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"Maharastra","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"Odisha","VerificationPending":"2","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"UP","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"6"}]  ;   
// var sampleData ; 
// $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
//    $http({
//      url : 'charts',
//         method : "POST"
//      }).then(function(response) {
//      sampleData =JSON.stringify(response.data);
//      }); 
//    
    
    // prepare jqxChart settings
    var settings = {
        title: "Enrollment Status",
        description: "State-Wise Enrollments",
        enableAnimations: true,
        showLegend: true,
        padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
        titlePadding: { left: 40, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
       // source: $scope.chartdata,
        source:  sampleData,
        rtl: true,
        xAxis:
            {
                dataField: 'State',
                showTickMarks: true,
                tickMarksInterval: 1,
                tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                unitInterval: 1,
                showGridLines: false,
                gridLinesInterval: 1,
                gridLinesColor: '#888888',
                axisSize: 'auto'
            },
        colorScheme: 'scheme01',
        seriesGroups:
            [
                {
                    type: 'stackedcolumn',
                    columnsGapPercent: 100,
                    seriesGapPercent: 5,
                    valueAxis:
                    {
                        unitInterval: 10,
                        minValue: 0,
                        maxValue: 100,
                        displayValueAxis: true,
                        description: 'Enrollments in Thousands',
                        axisSize: 'auto',
                        tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                        gridLinesColor: '#777777'
                    },
                    series: [
                            { dataField: 'AccountsOpened', displayText: 'AccountsOpened' },
                            { dataField: 'VerificationPending', displayText: 'VerificationPending' },
                            { dataField: 'Rejected', displayText: 'Rejected'}
                        ]
                }
            ]
    };
    $scope.chartSettings = settings;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    JQDemo.controller("charts", function ($scope, $timeout,$http) {
        // prepare chart data as an array
    //    var sampleData = [
    //            { State: 'Maharastra', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 25 },
    //            { State: 'Karnataka', AccountsOpened: 25, VerificationPending: 25, Rejected: 0},
    //            { State: 'Tamil Nadu', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 25 },
    //            { State: 'AP', AccountsOpened: 20, VerificationPending: 20, Rejected: 25},
    //            { State: 'Bihar', AccountsOpened: 0, VerificationPending: 20, Rejected: 25 },
    //            { State: 'Odisha', AccountsOpened: 30, VerificationPending: 0, Rejected: 30},
    //            { State: 'UP', AccountsOpened: 20, VerificationPending: 40, Rejected: 0 }
    //        ];
     
     var sampleData=[{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"AP","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"Calcutta","VerificationPending":"2","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"Delhi","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"5"},{"AccountsOpened":"2","State":"Maharastra","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"Odisha","VerificationPending":"2","Rejected":"1"},{"AccountsOpened":"1","State":"UP","VerificationPending":"1","Rejected":"6"}]  ;   
    // var sampleData ; 
    // $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
    //    $http({
    //      url : 'charts',
    //         method : "POST"
    //      }).then(function(response) {
    //      sampleData =JSON.stringify(response.data);
        // prepare jqxChart settings
        var settings = {
            title: "Enrollment Status",
            description: "State-Wise Enrollments",
            enableAnimations: true,
            showLegend: true,
            padding: { left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5 },
            titlePadding: { left: 40, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
           // source: $scope.chartdata,
            source:  sampleData,
            rtl: true,
            xAxis:
                {
                    dataField: 'State',
                    showTickMarks: true,
                    tickMarksInterval: 1,
                    tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                    unitInterval: 1,
                    showGridLines: false,
                    gridLinesInterval: 1,
                    gridLinesColor: '#888888',
                    axisSize: 'auto'
                },
            colorScheme: 'scheme01',
            seriesGroups:
                [
                    {
                        type: 'stackedcolumn',
                        columnsGapPercent: 100,
                        seriesGapPercent: 5,
                        valueAxis:
                        {
                            unitInterval: 10,
                            minValue: 0,
                            maxValue: 100,
                            displayValueAxis: true,
                            description: 'Enrollments in Thousands',
                            axisSize: 'auto',
                            tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                            gridLinesColor: '#777777'
                        },
                        series: [
                                { dataField: 'AccountsOpened', displayText: 'AccountsOpened' },
                                { dataField: 'VerificationPending', displayText: 'VerificationPending' },
                                { dataField: 'Rejected', displayText: 'Rejected'}
                            ]
                    }
                ]
        };
        $scope.chartSettings = settings;
    });
```

```
//              }); 
//
```